# Не записывается массив в файл

Tags: php

Изучаю PHP. Вот задание.
1. Создайте класс GuestBook, который будет удовлетворять следующим требованиям:

1. В конструктор передается путь до файла с данными гостевой книги, в нём же происходит чтение данных из нее (используйте защищенное свойство объекта для хранения данных)
2. Метод getData() возвращает массив записей гостевой книги
3. Метод append($text) добавляет новую запись к массиву записей
4. Метод save() сохраняет массив в файл

Сам код:

```
class GuestBook{
    public $path = __DIR__ . '/data.txt';
    public $text;
    protected $listGuest;

    public function __construct(){
         $this -> listGuest = file($this -> path);
    }

    public function getData(){
        return $this -> listGuest;
    }

    public function append($text){
        $this->text = $text;
        return $this->listGuest[] = $this->text;
    }

    public function save(){
        file_put_contents($this->path,$this->listGuest);
    }
}
```

# index.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/entry.php';
?>
<form method="post" action="entry.php">
    <input type="text" name="guest">
    <button type="submit">Новая запись</button>
</form>

<?php

$guestBook = new GuestBook();
$guestBook->getData();
$guestBook->text = $_POST['guest'];
$guestBook->append($guestBook->text);
$guestBook->save();
foreach ($guestBook->getData() as $guest){
    echo $guest . '<br>';
}
```

Новый массив не записывается в файл. Не могу понять почему. С ООП работаю в первые. Подскажите, где ошибка.

Comment: Это определение класса. Где работа с его методами?

Comment: скорее всего потому что ты путаешься между понятиями "файл" и "массив". ну и разумеется потому что **не пишешь внятно русским языком** что значит "низаписываеца"

Comment: @Ипатьев судя по всему человек просто создал класс и ждет когда кто-то вызовет методы класса.

Comment: я не думаю что он настолько не понимает что делает. плюс как минимум текущий класс пишет в файл слово Array

Comment: Почему `Array`? В `file_put_contents` можно передавать массив, он заимплодится. Про перенос эт я малость перегнул)

Comment: @u_mulder , прошу прощения. Добавил работу с методами.

Comment: Ну а  метод `save` где вызывается?

Comment: @Ипатьев, пока понимаю, что там происходит на интуитивном уровне. После обычного функционального, легкий культурный шок.

Comment: @u_mulder офигеть

Comment: @u_mulder, добавил. Все равно не появляется новая запись  в файле

Comment: а предыдущая запись случайно не меняется? вообще по идее приведенный код должен работать. ты скорее всего запускаешь не его а случайный результат хаотичных телодвижений.

Comment: плюс у меня вопросы (не имеют отношения к проблеме с сохранением). 1. зачем два раза присваивается значение $guestBook->text? 2. зачем вообще нужна эта переменная класса? 3. В задании написано "В конструктор передается путь до файла", но в коде я этого не вижу. 4. зачем два раза вызывается $guestBook->getData();?

Comment: Забыли саму тривиальную ошибку. Файл защищён от записи

Answer (score 0):

Окончательный вариант. Всем Спасибо за помощь!

```
<p>Форма для добавление нового пользователя:</p>
<form action="/6/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="guest">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>


<?php
class GuestBook{
    protected $data;
    public function __construct($path){
        $this->data = file($path);
    }
    public function getData(){
        return $this->data;
    }
    public function append($text){
        return $this->data[] = $text . "\n";
    }

    public function save(){
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/data.txt',$this->getData());
    }
}

$guestBook = new GuestBook(__DIR__ . '/data.txt');
if (!empty($_POST['guest'])){
    $guestBook->append($_POST['guest']);
    $guestBook->save();
}

foreach ($guestBook->getData() as $guest){
    echo $guest . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: $path не учитывается при записи в файл. Могу читать комментарии из одного файла, а писать в другой.

Comment: public function save($path){
        file_put_contents($path,$this->getData());
    }